# Android Push notification is not working on Model number- vs450pp having version 4.4.2

Tags: android, push-notification

I am getting push notification on Android phone on given model number but when I clicked on the notification, It disappear and doesn't open app. I would be grateful If anyone get me out from that problems.

Comment: It will be good..if you can share the code you implemented..or error you are getting..

Comment: Have you written builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Following Code May be work for you .

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class); //define your application activity name which you want to open.
        PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);


        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Uri soundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = (NotificationCompat.Builder) new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle("Application Title")
                .setContentText(message)
                .setContentIntent(pIntent)
                .setSound(soundUri); //This sets the sound to play

        notificationManager.notify(0, mBuilder.build());
```